# New class of finite groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I need to consider finite groups $G$ such that for any square-free number $d$ dividing the order of the group $G$, there exists a normal subgroup $H$ in $G$  such that either $H$ or $G/H$ has order $d$. Let us temporarily call such groups *square-free-normal*.

> **Problem**. Does the class of square-free-normal finite groups coincide with some known class of finite groups?

**Remark.** It is known that a finite nilpotent groups contain an normal subgroup of any order dividing the order of the group, so nilpotent finite groups are square-free-normal. On the other hand, diherdal groups $D_{2p}$ with prime $p$ are square-free-normal but not nilpotent.

> **Question.** What is the relation between square-free-normal finite groups and supersolvable finite groups? Is each supersolvable finite group square-free-normal?

**Remark**. Thank you for your comments, after which I arrive to the conclusion that square-free-normal supersolvable groups form a proper intermediate class between finite nilpotent groups and finite supersolvable groups. Im I right? Or this is known and has some other name? (I means "square-free-normal supersolvable")?

Comment: If $A$ is cyclic of order $n$ (let's say square free) and $B$ is any finite group of some order all of whose prime factors occur in $n$ then $A\times B$ is square-free-normal. I would assume that one might want to somehow exclude these degenerate examples.

Comment: No, this case is Ok with me. In fact, my aim is to represent a "nice" (in my case square-free-normal supersolvable) group $G$ as the extension of a group $H$ and a group $K$ such that one of them is square-free and the other has order $k^2$ for some $k$ and contains a subgroup of order $k$.  For this purpose I need square-free-normality + the CLT (the Converge Lagrange Theorem) property, possessed by supersolvable groups. In any case, thank you for the comment.

Comment: It sounds as though you mean the Converse Lagrange Theorem, which says that if $d$ is a positive integer with $d \mid |L|$ and $L$ is (for example) supersolvable, then $L$ has a subgroup of order $d$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $G=(C_7\rtimes C_3)\times(C_5\rtimes C_2)$.

Then $G$ is supersolvable but doesn't have a normal subgroup of order $7\times 2$ or $3\times 5$.

Comment: Thank you. This answers my second question, but rather confirms the first one, name that the class of square-free-normal (supersolvable) groups rather does not coincide with anything known?